# Parsing rdf xml file with dom on python 3.6

Tags: xml, dom, rdf, python-3.6

*I am using python 3.6 and the I am parsing the RDF xml script below with DOM. From this script, I want to :
1 - know for each student: the ID of the student, the ID of the lab to which he belongs to, the name of the lab, the location of the lab(which city), the geographic position of the lab (latitude and longitude)
2 - put all these information into a python dict as follows:
    student_dict = {"48F8":("_D6EA",Carbone_14,City_1,(169,246)),etc... }

Any help would be grateful. Thank you in advance*

---

```
<Student ID="48F8">
  <Name>James</Name>
  <Lab ID="#_D6EA"/>
</Student>
<Student ID="48F5">
  <Name>Adel</Name>
  <Lab ID="#_D6EA"/>
</Student>
<Student ID="48B9">
  <Name>Albert</Name>
  <Lab ID="#_M001"/>
</Student>
<Lab_Physics ID="_D6EA">
  <Name>Carbone_14</Name>
  <Location resource="#_1000"/>
</Lab_Physics>
<Lab_Physics ID="_A6EC">
  <Name>Magnetism</Name>
  <Location resource="#_2000"/>
</Lab_Physics>
<Lab_Biology ID="_M001">
  <Name>Molecule</Name>
  <Location resource="#_1000"/>
</Lab_Biology>
<Location ID="_1000">
  <Name>City_1</Name>
</Location>
<Location ID="_2000">
  <Name>City_2</Name>
</Location>
<Position ID="_P1A000">
  <Location resource="#_1000"/>
  <Lat>169</Lat>
  <Lon>246</Lon>
</Position>
<Position ID="_P1B000">
  <Location resource="#_2000"/>
  <Lat>250</Lat>
  <Lon>400</Lon>
</Position>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

As RDF exists with many serializations, you can be certain that you are doing it wrong if you are looking at it from an XML-centric perspective. Rather, you want to find a library that provides you with an abstraction of the [rdf data model](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-primer/).

In python, [rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib) is usually my go-to. The documentation for parsing shows how you [load an file](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_parsing.html).

```py
import rdflib
g=rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("demo.xml", format="xml")
```

Next, you'll either want to execute a [SPARQL query](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/) on the graph to locate the resources that you are interested in, or you'll want to [use the api](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to manually parse statements within the graph.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I tried to install "rdflib" via pip install rdflib on my command line but it does not install. I also tried by downloading the package, coming back to my command line and CD to the folder where the package is saved. Then, when I type: python setup.py >>> it does not work. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any generic/common installation problems. I always use pip for installing rdflib and haven't encountered issues on any platform to date. The [Getting started with RDFLib](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/gettingstarted.html) section of their documentation should walk you through basic installation. Failing that, I'd ask a python/rdflib specific question on stackoverflow regarding your installation problems or direct a question to their mailing list.

Comment: I have finally installed the rdflib. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help. If this answer solved your issue, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: I progress but my issue is still pending. In the meantime, I am trying to make some queries on the graph using SPARQL in order to answer to my request above but I have no idea how to make these queries. If you can provide a simple example, i would be great. Thank you.